# Is it true that P(X|Y)=P(Z|Y) implies P(X) = P(Z)?

Tags: probability

Something feels intuitively off about this but I can't find a way to algebraically manipulate it to be false.

Thanks :)

Comment: Please tell us what the implicit quantifiers are.  Is this a statement about particular events $X,Y,Z$ or about *all* events $Y$ for arbitrary $X$ and $Z$ or about something else?

Comment: Why do you think this is right, or where did you encounter this impication?

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional probability,
$$P(X\mid Y) = \frac{P(X \cap Y)}{P(Y)}$$

So, if $P(X\mid Y) = P(Z\mid Y)$,  then
$$ P(X\cap Y) = P(Z\cap Y)$$

This leads to $P(X) = P(Z),$ **only if $Y$ is independent of both $X$ and $Z$**. Because, this leads to
$$P(X)\cdot P(Y) = P(Z) \cdot P(Y)$$
$$P(X) = P(Z)$$

I hope this make sense to you.

Comment: I disagree with your statement in bold. Let events $X=Y=Z$, $Y$ is not independent of $X$ and/or $Z$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true in general. Contradiction is one way to solve this. Here is an example:

Let's toss a coin that we don't know if it is fair ($P($Head$)=p=\frac{1}{2}$) or biased with $p$ something different than $\frac{1}{2}$, e.g. $p=\frac{2}{3}$. And, call the events $X$,$Y$,$Z$ as follows:

$X$: Toss comes up Head, $Y:$ Coin is Fair, i.e. $p=\frac{1}{2}$, $Z$: Toss comes up Tails. Also, let $P(Y)=\frac{1}{2}$ to ease things.

We know that $P(Z|Y)=P(X|Y)=\frac{1}{2}$. But, using total probability theorem,

$P(Z)=P(Z|Y)P(Y)+P(Z|Y')P(Y')=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{5}{12}$
Similarly, 
$P(X)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{2}=\frac{7}{12}$. So, they're not equal.

Comment: The original question is not very clear. In your example, $\Pr(X|Y')=\frac 2 3$, but $\Pr(Z|Y') = \frac 1 3$. So your example does not follow the conditions given in the question.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't even interested in $P(X|Y')$ and $P(Z|Y')$, or anything other than $P(X|Y)$ and $P(Z|Y)$.